# Creating Auto run on USB device

Tags: python, autorun

I want to make A project which the disk on key I insert will run a python file  that blocks access to the files in the disk on key , therefore I need to make an autorun on the disk on key to run that code
I was trying reading about the autorun and as I found it was blocked on windows 7 and above 
Is there any way to do it in win7 and above?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the autorun feature in newer versions of windows.By default, it is disabled for security purposes so in short you cannot use autorun feature without enabling autorun.
Edit: I searched a bit and it is nearly impossible to autorun a program in any other computer without admin privileges however this [link](http://www.visualdesigning.com/articles/how-to-create-autorun-usb-drive/) might help you as they claim it worked.

Comment: Any other ways? because I need it to be available on any computer since the idea of the project is protecting the device on any pc

Comment: I just want it to run a python file as soon as I connect the usb no matter on which computer